# Schema to validate null entries

Tags: yaml, schema.yml

I am new to yml.

My yml data file may or may not contain names under "reference:" tag in it. Basically, it could just be empty, So for successful validation I made it `'required: no'`

```
type: map
mapping:
  file:
    type: seq
    sequence:
      - type: map
        mapping:
          project:
            type: str
            required: yes
          sub:
            type: str
            required: yes
          source:
            type: str
            required: yes
          reference:
            type: seq
            required: no
            sequence:
              - type: map
                mapping:
                  name:
                    type: str
                    required: no
                    unique: yes
```

When I try to validate yml using `Kwalify.pm` , it fails with issue:-

```
 warning: Use of uninitialized value $data in concatenation (.) or string at /home/nv/utils/MFT/perl/lib/Kwalify-1.22/lib/Kwalify.pm
```

Need yml experts help in this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sequence:`, standing separately without following more-indented content, produces a key-value pair with `sequence` as key and an empty scalar as value. An empty scalar will be processed either into an empty string or `null`, neither of which is a sequence as required by your schema.

To have an empty mapping, write `sequence: []`.

Comment: flyx,for which sequence: we need to mark {} , Actually i tried to add latter one with (sequence: {} ... ) in my schema and it still fails with same validation error.

Comment: @RAMA You need to add it to your data file. Also, the error looks like a bug in the Perl script. It could be that the bug is triggered by non-conforming data, in which case it might go away, but if it doesn't you'll want to file a bug report with that script.

Comment: Adding 'reference:[]' helps validating yml successfully.

Comment: @RAMA A yes of course, I misread the schema. *sequence* being an actual sequence, not a mapping, will need `[]`. I updated my answer.